# MySQL Select statement return null when inside a Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm creating a trigger in MySQL but have a slight issue.

Here's the trigger code :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cfmaj$$
CREATE TRIGGER cfmaj AFTER INSERT ON vtiger_cf_608
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE sortid,pickvalue INT;
SET @pickvalue = (SELECT id FROM vtiger_picklistvalues_seq),
@sort_id = (SELECT max(sortid) FROM vtiger_role2picklist WHERE roleid = 'H5' AND picklistid = 47); 
UPDATE vtiger_cf_608_seq SET id = id+1;
UPDATE vtiger_picklistvalues_seq SET id = id+1;
INSERT INTO vtiger_role2picklist (roleid,picklistvalueid,picklistid,sortid) VALUES ('H5',@pickvalue,47,@sort_id);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Everything works fine except that @sort_id equal null. Funny thing is when querying with just

> (SELECT max(sortid) FROM vtiger_role2picklist WHERE roleid = 'H5' AND picklistid = 47)

,the query works perfectly.

I'm a bit confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using

```
SET @pickvalue = (SELECT id FROM vtiger_picklistvalues_seq),
@sort_id = (SELECT max(sortid) FROM vtiger_role2picklist WHERE roleid = 'H5' AND picklistid = 47);
```

instead of

```
SET pickvalue = (SELECT id FROM vtiger_picklistvalues_seq),
sort_id = (SELECT max(sortid) FROM vtiger_role2picklist WHERE roleid = 'H5' AND picklistid = 47);
```

Take into account that 
    `set = @sort_id` is totally different from `set = sort_id`

Then on your

```
INSERT INTO vtiger_role2picklist (roleid,picklistvalueid,picklistid,sortid) VALUES ('H5',@pickvalue,47,@sort_id);
```

You're using @sortid instead of your sort_id variable, which has not the value previously set.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually using @ is correct. The issue here was in my Declare statement. The variable was misspelled. And there I roamed for more than an hour searching for a solution. But you helped me take a closer look at my variable which pointed me toward the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should you not be using `@var := value`? `:=` makes it into an assignment, otherwise MySQL interprets it as an equality test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in sql, but maybe it's because you don't use `SELECT max(sortid) AS xxx`.

If it doesn't work, try to do a `SELECT ... INTO`:

```
DECLARE var_sort_id INT;

SELECT MAX(sortid) AS maxsortid INTO var_sort_id FROM vtiger_role2picklist WHERE roleid = 'H5' AND picklistid = 47;
```

Hope it works.

EDIT : Why dont't you separate each query, like:

```
SET pickvalue = (SELECT id FROM vtiger_picklistvalues_seq);
SET sort_id = (SELECT max(sortid) FROM vtiger_role2picklist WHERE roleid = 'H5' AND picklistid = 47);
```

Comment: Seperating the query doesn't change anything. Already tried it.